# Where can I find the source code for selfdestruct()?

Tags: selfdestruct

I'm trying to look into the Ethereum repository but I can't find a file for the functions. I want to know how `selfdestruct()` is implemented, but I also would like to look at other functions.

Answer (score 1):

The `selfdestruct()` method is a function that's provided by the Solidity compiler, so it's a Solidity language feature, not an Ethereum (virtual machine) function. So the source code you want to be looking through to find out how it's actually accomplished is the [Solidity compiler](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity).

Comment: I tried using the search function for 'selfdestruct' but the closest thing I could come to its implementation is https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/blob/8eead553aff1ec30c3d1b15ae9b2929b887ede49/libsolidity/ast/Types.cpp. I'm not sure if that's it.